# Joining two multi-column lists side by side

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I guess this is a fairly simple question, but I haven't had much luck with using `Join[...]` or `Transpose[...]`. I have two data sets which are multi-column lists, I simply want to turn them into one multi-column data set.

```
ListA = {{α, β, γ}, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
ListB = {{δ, ϵ, ϕ}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}};

ListC = {
  {α, β, γ, δ, ϵ, ϕ}, 
  {1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9}, 
  {4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12}
};
```

If `ListA` and `ListB` are the two starting files and `ListC` is the desired form. So I simply want to stitch `ListB` to the right of `ListA`.

Comment: `Join[ListA, ListB, 2]`

Comment: @Kuba thanks, annoyingly simple

Comment: Indeed, I dare you to find a duplicate with such simple answer. I bet there are many.

Comment: @Kuba I've been using Mathematica for 25 years and I had no idea `Join` takes a level argument!

Comment: @Pillsy That's because it's hidden [at the top of of the doc page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Join.html). :)

Comment: @Michael, to be fair to Pillsy, that level argument only started in version 6. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ArrayFlatten[{{ListA, ListB}}]
```

> {{α, β, γ, δ, ϵ, ϕ}, {1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9}, {4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12}}

Answer (score 3):

```
Flatten[#] & /@ Transpose[{listA, listB}]
```

or

```
Transpose[{listA, listB}] /. {{a___}, {b___}} -> {a, b}
```